# write test for scanning input in function

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

This is my code, and I can't write a test for scanning input in the second function. The first function is for separate words that they contain + or - or " ". The second function is for categorizing query, for example you give "mom dad +sister +sisi -brother -bro"  and then split the word by " " and then calling the first function.

```
package Phase2;
import Phase2.QueryKeeper;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class QueryCategorizer {

    private final QueryKeeper queryKeeper = new QueryKeeper();

    private void separateBySign(String[] query) {
        Set<String> plusContain = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> minusContain = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> withoutContain = new HashSet<>();

        for (String queryIterator : query) {
            if (queryIterator.contains("+")) {
                plusContain.add(queryIterator.substring(1));
            } else if (queryIterator.contains("-")) {
                minusContain.add(queryIterator.substring(1));
            } else {
                withoutContain.add(queryIterator);
            }
        }
        queryKeeper.addAllSets(plusContain,minusContain,withoutContain);

    }

    public void categorizeQuery() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a query");
        String query = scanner.nextLine();
        separateBySign(query.split(" "));
    }

    public QueryKeeper getQueryKeeper() {
        return queryKeeper;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it that you can’t test `categorizeQuery()` because you can’t mock `System.in`?

Comment: Actually, I have problem with writing test for my functions... and i wrote this line   ```System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(query.getBytes())); ```   for mock ```System.in```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the result of a design flaw in your code structure.

`categorizeQuery()` mixes multiple different tasks:

- getting raw input from the user (`scanner.nextLine()`),
- parsing input into program-usable form (split into array),
- processing the search words (by calling `separateBySign()`).

(The same applies to `separateBySign()` as well.)

Such a method is not only hard to unit-test, but also hard to maintain in the long run.

Change your program structure so that all your steps return a result, and have a top-level method call all the steps one-by-one, passing the results from the previous step as parameter into the next one. Then it's easy to unit-test the individual steps. You know what the method is to return if you pass it some given parameters. And if one test fails, you know exactly what processing step is responsible.

Then, the fact fades away that mocking `System.in` isn't easy. The only step left using `System.in` is the method to read a raw line of text from, and if this one-liner doesn't get tested by your unit test, it's okay - it's well tested in the JRE release process.